# Pressing back button on Activity Dialog stopping first activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am currently working on an android project and I am having an issue when the user presses the back button on an activity that uses the dialog theme.

Basically I have an activity, lets call it MyActivity and a second activity which uses the @android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog called MyDialog.

When the MyDialog activity is shown on the screen, the activity dialogue starts up as expected in a dialogue, but when the user presses the back button, the dialog activity closes as is expected, but the starting activity i.e. MyActivity seems to finish, I just get a blank screen.

I'm not setting any flags for starting the activity so I don't understand why it is doing this behaviour. Below is the code that I am using to start the dialog activity.

```
public OnItemClickListener mListView = new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        String selection = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(selection, "\n");
        String name = st.nextToken();
        String username = st.nextToken();
        Intent intent = new Intent(PasswordList.this, LoginSelectionManager.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        intent.putExtra("username", username);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

**UPDATE**
As request below is the code of the onResume method of MyActivity

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    populateListArray();
}
```

All this is doing is call a function that repopulates the ListView array adapter with data from the database. Below is the code for this

```
private void populateListArray()
{

    ArrayList<Spanned> passwords = managePasswordList.getPasswordList();
    if (passwords != null)
    {
        passwordArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, passwords);
        setListAdapter(passwordArrayAdapter);
        passwordArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        myListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: add your `onResume` of `MyActivity`....

Comment: I've added the code for onResume

Comment: did you put a log in `onFinish` and check to make sure it is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put logs in `onFinish` of both the activities and see which ones actually finish... I doubt the dialog activity finishes on pressing back..

The fact that you get a blank screen means your activity has not finished yet,  its just that the listview is empty.

So the next question that arises is why your passwords list is null in the `onResume`. Do you really need to set the adapter in the `onResume`? See moving it to `onCreate`..

Comment: Its definetely not to do with the adapter being empty. When the activity is first created the onCreate sets the adapter fine. The onResume populates the adapter again as the data can change from other activities so it refreshes the adapter. I don't think it is actually showing me the list view as the Ice Cream Sandwich bar doesn't show either. Its literally just a blank screen with only the android notification bar

Comment: Put logs in `onFinish` of both the activities and see which ones actually finish... I doubt the dialog activity finishes on pressing back...

Comment: I've marked this as correct but it was the logging the onFinish that helped. I noticed that it was because from another activity, the first one that launches that launces MyActivity I was for some reason by mistake adding the no history flag so when I was pressing the back button it was returning to the first activity. And it was blank as it shows certain layouts depending on certain if statements and none of them were true so no layout was shown

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the flags for the intent with which you start the new Activity. It can be done by intent.setFlags(Intent. ...), where intent is an Intent Object. Check Android documentation for more details.

Comment: thanks, I've tried using ``intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`` but hasn't made any difference. Still doing the same thing